# How do you set the style for multiple Separators in JavaFX using css?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a layout where I have five horizontal Separators. I want them to all have the same default style but with the option to change any one of them at a later date.

The default style I want is a solid single pixel height black line.

I don't have a custom class for the Separators so I don't think a style class is appropriate. Therefore I thought that ids might be the better idea. So I have something like this:

```
Separator topSeparator = new Separator();
topSeparator.setId("top-separator");
Separator middleSeparator = new Separator();
middleSeparator.setId("middle-separator");
etc...
```

and then in my css this:

```
#top-separator .line{
-fx-border-color: black;
-fx-border-width: 1 0 0 0;
}
#middle-separator .line{
-fx-border-color: black;
-fx-border-width: 1 0 0 0;
}
etc...
```

Is this the best way of specifying a single pixel solid black line?

Is using ids appropriate over style classes, and if so, is there anyway I can specify a parent style so that I don't have to repeat the `-fx-border-color: black;` and `-fx-border-width: 1 0 0 0;` five times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the best way of specifying a single pixel solid black line?

This is a perfectly good way to do it, assuming it gives you what you need.

> Is using ids appropriate over style classes, and if so, is there
>   anyway I can specify a parent style so that I don't have to repeat

Ids should be unique, whereas multiple `Node`s can share the same class. Use ids if there is a specific style you want for one particular `Node` and classes if there is (or perhaps could be) a collection of `Node`s that should be styled the same way.

You can use both techniques together, if you need:

```
Separator topSeparator = new Separator();
topSeparator.setId("top-separator");
topSeparator.getStyleClass().add("my-separator");
Separator middleSeparator = new Separator();
middleSeparator.setId("middle-separator");
middleSeparator.getStyleClass().add("my-separator");
```

and then:

```
.my-separator .line {
  -fx-border-color: black ;
  -fx-border-width: 1 0 0 0 ;
}

#top-separator .line {
  /* rules specific to top separator */
}

#middle-separator .line {
  /* rules specific to middle separator */
}
/* etc ... */
```

Comment: OK thanks. It does give me what I need but it just seems a bit of a hack to use a one pixel border rather than using the Separator itself. In fact, I'm not sure what the Separator is actually doing in this case - couldn't I use any Node to achieve this if all I'm using is a border?

Comment: The "line" representing the separator is actually just an empty region. See [css docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#separator). So yes, you could use a `Region` directly, but you'd have to write the code to make sure the layout worked. The default stylesheet styles it using a border, so it's easier just to override the border rules. The other option would involve both turning off the border, and then setting the background color and a minimum height.